# Should stackexchange sites be differentiated on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web

I sometimes use the mobile version of SE websites and, with the exception of [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) and [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), all SE sites seem to render with the same generic stackexchange theme.

[image: gamedev.se desktop and mobile renders]
[image: math.se desktop and mobile renders]

Could sites use *elements of* their respective themes (like color & the top left corner graphic) for mobile render?

This makes identifying what is in the browser window faster and less error-prone, especially when flicking between tabs:

[image: tab view current mobile renders]

vs

[image: tab view w desktop themes]

Comment: They do if you switch to "Full site" with "Responsiveness" enabled. I don't know why this isn't the default though?

Comment: I much prefer to have the same template for all Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt no way!! I find it is not as easy to identify what is in the browser tab when the icon is that generic SE icon. I also find it very "draft"-looking and it reminds me of when these sites were just starting up from area51 and didn't even have customized design yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're viewing is the old default mobile template for mobile sites. I'm surprised that thing is not retired and removed already.

Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page and hit the “full site” link at the end of the footer. It will instead take you to a mobile responsive version of the full site that uses all of its distinct site elements:

[image]